# Conditional formatting if a cell does not equal one of three values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a dataset as below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCB32.jpg]

I want to apply conditional formatting that will format a cell if the value in that cell is **not** `100`, `50` or `0` (ie I want it to pick up A5 and format it)

I'm new to conditional formatting and haven't been able to figure this out yet. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: Using a macro is one of the options. Have you been to MSDN?

Comment: while this is not really the right forum for this, in short you would use an equation that looked something like =AND(A5<>0,A5<>50,A5<>100). if you select the whole range and aim your equation to begin with the first row selected (if you select A1:A10, substitute A1 for A5) it will carry over for all the range.

Comment: @Rachcha - a macro is unnecessary here, just some basic logic i think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove any previous attempts at a Conditional Formatting Rule.
2. Select A2:C5 and use Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule.
3. Choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for *Format values where this formula is true:*
           =not(or(A2=0, A2=50, A2=100))
4. Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select some formatting change.
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the formatting and then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

You results should resemble the following.

[image: Conditional Formatting Rule]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! Thats done exactly what I needed

Comment: @pnuts - Not so much VTC as VT-Migrate. This really is a SuperUser question. My vote just got caught up with others that voted in different categories.